# how to Install xvfb and run with python and selenium?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-import

I'm trying to use Xvfb to run headless browser. following process which I followed so far
1. Installed xvfb `sudo apt-get install xvfb`
2. Created virtualenv, 
3. Installed xvfbwrapper
4. run following code

```
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb


class TestPages(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.xvfb = Xvfb(width=1280, height=720)
        self.addCleanup(self.xvfb.stop)
        self.xvfb.start()
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.addCleanup(self.browser.quit)

    def testUbuntuHomepage(self):
        self.browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com')
        self.assertIn('Ubuntu', self.browser.title)

    def testGoogleHomepage(self):
        self.browser.get('http://www.google.com')
        self.assertIn('Google', self.browser.title)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

But I'm getting following error, Even I tried installing this with sudo but no effect.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xvfbwrapper.py", line 4, in <module>
    from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
  File "/home/ubuntu/unclescrooz/src/robinhood/xvfbwrapper.py", line 4, in <module>
    from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
ImportError: cannot import name Xvfb
```

Same issue with `pyvirtualdisplay`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyvirtualdisplay.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
  File "/m4k/projects/scrapper/stock/robinhood/pyvirtualdisplay.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
ImportError: cannot import name Display
```

With following code

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

Comment: Hey there! I have the issue. How did you resolve? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Rename your files `xvfbwrapper.py` and `pyvirtualdisplay.py` to something else than the name of the module you import.